# How to add event handlers on elements created dynamically which are not present at the start

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am very new to javascript and currently am making a to-do list like [this](https://codepen.io/JohnPaulFich/pen/MXmzzM).

I am trying to make the list item turn green when clicked using javascript. This is my current code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TODO</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&family=PT+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&family=Rubik:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7fa743e7fb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WORK TO-DOS</h1>
    <p id="desc">Enter text into the input field to add items to your list.</p>
    <p id="compl-desc">Click the item to mark it as complete.</p>
    <p id="rem-desc">Click the "X" to remove the item from your list.</p>
    <section id="input-block">
        <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="New Item">
        <button id="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pen"></i></button>
    </section>
    <ul class="todo-area"></ul>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- tst div -->
    <!-- <div class='test-div'>
        <span>lor</span>
        <button id="delete-li">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        </button>
    </div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #04a1bf;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: center; */
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3.0rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* changing colors */
#desc {
    color: yellow;
}

#compl-desc {
    color:greenyellow
}

#rem-desc {
    color: #025f70;
}

section {
    width: 70%;
    height: 60px;
}

#todo {
    height: 55%;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    /* margin-right: 10px; */
}

#submit {
    border: none;
    height: 55%;
    width: 7%;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: #025f70;
    color:aliceblue;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    /* transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1); */
}

#submit:hover {
    background-color: #02798f;
    color: bisque;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 55%;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.todo-area {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0%;
    width: 60%;
}

.todo-item {
    /* width: 60%; */
    background-color: #4eb9cd;
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #025f70;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.todo-item:hover {
    background-color: #76cfe0;
}

.todo-item-complete {
    background-color: #51df70;
    color: #0f8d2a;
}

#delete-li {
    border: none;
    background-color: #4eb9cd;
    margin-right:2%;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.todo-item:hover #delete-li {
    background-color: #76cfe0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const todoUl = document.querySelector('.todo-area');
const input = document.querySelector('#todo');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');
console.log('input', input['value'])

function createLi(inputText) {
    // this function creates the li with the delete button
    // creating the Li first
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // add class to li
    li.classList.add('todo-item');
    //  making the button
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    delBtn.setAttribute('id', 'delete-li');
    // icon
    const btnIcon = document.createElement('i');
    btnIcon.classList.add('fa-solid');
    btnIcon.classList.add('fa-xmark');
    // adding that to the delete button
    delBtn.appendChild(btnIcon)
    
    // adding text to the element from the input
    // creating a span
    const liSpan = document.createElement('span');
    liSpan.innerText = inputText;
    li.appendChild(liSpan);
    li.appendChild(delBtn);
    
    return li
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // getting value in text box
    let todoText = input.value;
    console.log('button clicked');
    console.log(todoText);
    // adding to the ul element
    if(todoText !== "") { 
        let newLi = createLi(todoText);
        // adding class to the li
        // newLi.classList.add('todo-item');
        todoUl.appendChild(newLi);
    }
    // resetting the text box blank again
    input.value = '';
})

// getting all the list items
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-item');

// turning them green once they are clicked
for(let li of listItems) {
    // adding an onclick event on them
    li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // adding the active class
        console.log('LI CMD');
        li.classList.toggle('todo-item-complete');
    })
}
```

Which clearly is not working. Although I think I have an idea why is it not working. I need to know how to set event handlers on elements that are dynamically generated as a result of some action in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add eventListener while creating the `li`
like

```
function createLi(inputText) {
    // this function creates the li with the delete button
    // creating the Li first
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // add class to li
    li.classList.add('todo-item');
    //  making the button
    const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    delBtn.setAttribute('id', 'delete-li');
    // icon
    const btnIcon = document.createElement('i');
    btnIcon.classList.add('fa-solid');
    btnIcon.classList.add('fa-xmark');
    // adding that to the delete button
    delBtn.appendChild(btnIcon)
    
    // adding text to the element from the input
    // creating a span
    const liSpan = document.createElement('span');
    liSpan.innerText = inputText;
    li.appendChild(liSpan);
    li.appendChild(delBtn);
        li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // adding the active class
        console.log('LI CMD');
        li.classList.toggle('todo-item-complete');
    })
    
    return li
}
```